# SharePoint 2010: Create "Alert Me" button

Tags: sharepoint-2010, alerts

Hopefully this is an easy one...

I need to create an "Alert Me" button on my custom SharePoint masterpage which when clicked, will direct the user to a **pre-populated** "New Alert" page for that particular site/list. The OOTB blog site template already features this exact same button at the bottom of the default.aspx page, it's markup is as follows:

```
http://server/currentsite/_layouts/SubNew.aspx?List={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}&Source=http://server/currentsite/default.aspx
```

Does anyone know if there is an OOTB control or web part that I can just drop into my page layout to reproduce this?

Obviously I could create the button dynamically in the codebehind of my page layout if need be, but I'd be surprised if there isn't a pre-written control already.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those insterested, I ended up rolling my own usercontrol for this. Code is as follows:

**HTML**

---

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="AlertHyperLink" runat="server"><img alt="Alert me" src="/_layouts/images/menualert.gif" title="Alert me to any changes that get made to this site." /></asp:HyperLink>
```

**C#**

---

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If the current page is not associated with a list, then hide the list-sensitive tools.
    if (SPContext.Current.List != null)
    {
        this.AlertHyperLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format(
            "{0}/_layouts/SubNew.aspx?List={{{1}}}&Source={2}",
            SPContext.Current.Web.Url,
            SPContext.Current.List.ID.ToString(),
            this.Server.UrlEncode(this.Page.Request.Url.ToString()));
    }
    else
    {
        this.AlertHyperLink.Visible = false;
    }
}
```